# Orthogonal basis of orthogonal complement

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $$U = \{\vec{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n : x_1=x_2=...=x_n\}$$
I have to find orthogonal basis of  $$U^{\bot}$$
I was trying to use the Gram–Schmidt process but I suppose it isn't working in this case. Is there any simple solution to this problem?

Comment: $\vec{x} \in \mathbb{R}$ or $\vec{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ or $\vec{x} \in \mathbb{R}^m$ for any $m \geq n$?

Answer (score 1):

You want to find the vectors $\vec{y} = \left(\begin{array}{c} y_1 \\ \vdots \\ y_n\end{array}\right)$ such that $\left(\begin{array}{c} y_1 \\ \vdots \\ y_n\end{array}\right)\cdot\left(\begin{array}{c} 1 \\ \vdots \\ 1\end{array}\right) = 0$ (since every $\vec{x}\in U$ is a scalar multiple of this vector).

Thus what you have is the single equation $y_1 + \cdots + y_n = 0$. There are $n-1$ free parameters. Letting $y_n = -y_1 - \cdots - y_{n-1}$, can you see what a basis is?

Comment: Yeah, but this basis isn't orthogonal.

Comment: Right but you can do Gram Schmidt to get an orthogonal basis.